# Linked List Null Error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have written the following code to compute the sum of all the even entries in a `LinkedList`. However, I keep getting a `NullPointerException` because of the line where I use `(n.getNext).getNext()`.
Could any of guys tell me as to why this is happening?

Here is the piece of code I'm referring to:

```
public int sumEven() {
    return sumEven(head);
}

// private sumEven helper
private int sumEven(IntListNode n) {
    int nodeNumber=1;
    int count=0;
    if(n.getNext() == null && nodeNumber%2 == 0) {
        return n.getValue();
    } else if((n.getNext()).getNext() == null && nodeNumber%2 == 0) {
        return n.getValue();
    } else {
        nodeNumber++;
        if(nodeNumber%2 == 0) {
            count+=n.getValue();
            return count+ sumEven(n.getNext());
        } else {
            return count + sumEven(n.getNext());
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: if n is null, n.getNext() will throw an exception

Comment: And if n.getNext() is null, n.getNext().getNext() will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Because what if: In the first if statement n.getNext() is null but nodeNumber%2 is not equal to 0
So you go to the next if statement which says n.getNext().getNext() == null where already the first getNext() is null since it passed the first part of the previous if statement but failed the if statement because of the nodeNumber%2 == 0 part.

Ex: nodeNumber = 1 and n.getNext() = null

First if(true && false) => false

Second if(ERROR) Cuz the previous if statement has the first part true which says n.getNext() is null

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your input, but I am still unsure as to how it would look code-wise. Should I include another else if statement for when n.getNext()==null and nodeNumber%2!=0?

Comment: Try to switch the conditions in the if statement so it will be like this:
if(nodeNumber%2 == 0 && n.getNext() == null )
...
else  if(nodeNumber%2 == 0 && n.getNext().getNext() == null)

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems in the code. How about rethink the strategy? If you want to make it recursive, you can assume that the private method sumEven() will always be called with an even node. Then all that private method does is add up whatever that it is called with.

The following code is not tested but shows what I mean.

```
public int sumEven() {
    return sumEven(head,0);
}

private int sumEven(IntListNode n, int total) {
    if(n==null) return total;

    total += n.getValue();  // sums up running total

    if(n.getNext()==null) return total;

    return sumEven(n.getNext().getNext(),total); // calls next even node with current running total
}
```